# Is GetHashCode strong enough or do I need another hash function?

Tags: c#, .net, hash

I'am implementing data serialization and I've encounter a problem.
I've got:

- 4 byte fields:

  - Values range 0-255
  - Values range 0- 4
  - Values range 0-255
  - Values range 0- 100
- and 1 int field(only positive values)

I've got an idea to convet all to byte array(lenght 8) or int array(lenght 2) and get C# GetHashCode method

Is GetHashCode strong enough to use as identifier for this data?
Or someone has better idea, maybe?

EOG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetHashCode isn't meant to create a unique identifier - its primary use is for assigning values to buckets in hashed data structures (like HashTable) - see http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/.  When I need a unique identifier for an object, and for some reason the object itself doesn't provide one, I usually just fall back on GUIDs.  They are trivial to generate in C# and guaranteed to be unique within the scope of whatever you're doing.

Comment: They are not guaranteed to be unique, it is just immensely likely that they are.

Answer (score 1):

GetHashCode is purely for hashing in dictionary. You should not use it as identifier anywhere because of possible [hash collisions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx). It returns Int32 and for String for example it is clearly possible to have more than 2,147,483,647 unique strings. Two different strings can have the same hash code. Having said that you have two options:

1) If you need your identifier to be derived from the actual values. For example if you need to quickly tell if you already have new Object persisted without deserializing all objects and comparing them to object in question. You can use [ComputeHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx) on SHA1 for example.

2) If you don't need identifier to be derived from actual values you can simply generate  [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) like [bbogovich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032245/is-gethashcode-strong-enough-or-do-i-need-another-hash-function/7032322#7032322) have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetHashCode()` value for ints and longs (< int.MaxValue) is the same as the value, But for array's the value is not stable. So don't use it.

Why not convert the entire structure to a `long` as use that?